# for loop doesn't work with if else condition

Tags: python

So I want to do looping calculation over a list and it didn't work out. I want a new list with `(1+log10(i))` inside:

```py
    l = [115, 10, 2, 0]

    for i in l:
        l_1 = []
        if i == 0:
            l_1.append(i)
        else:
            l_1.append(1+np.log10(i))

    print(l_1)
    [0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new list in each loop pass, simple take it out:

```
l = [115, 10, 2, 0]
l_1 = []
for i in l:
    if i == 0:
        l_1.append(i)
    else:
        l_1.append(1+np.log10(i))
```

The pythonic way of doing this would be with a comprehension:

```
l_1 = [1+np.log10(i) if i != 0 else 0 for i in l]
```

Comment: Ah, 30 seconds faster :)

Answer (score 1):

or you could take full advantage of numpy:

```
import numpy as np

l = np.array((115, 10, 2, 0))
r = 1 + np.log10(np.where(l != 0, l, 0.1))
# [ 3.06069784  2.          1.30103     0.        ]
```

using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to weed out the `0` (and replacing it by `0.1` such that `np.log10(x) = 1` which will result in `0` after the `+1`).

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that `for i in l` gives you the values in i not the index so you only add one value, the last one.

here is a list comprehension that do what you want:

```
import numpy as np

l = [115, 10, 2, 0]
l_1 = [1+np.log10(i) if i !=0 else i for i in l]
print(l_1)
```